# set environment variables for ant script

Tags: ant, intellij-idea, rubymine

does anyone knows how to set additional environment variables for an ant script from within intellij-idea/rubymine? The part of the ant script which uses the environment variable looks as below:

```
  <property environment="env"/>
  <fail unless="env.IDEA_HOME" message="IDEA_HOME must be set."/>
```

What I've tried so far:

- Passing an environment variable on startup to intellij
- Settings -> Path Variables
- Ant Build -> Properties
- Ant Build -> Execution -> Ant command line

Comment: Option 1 would have worked. (works for me )

Comment: Ant Build/Properties/Properties tab/ specify the full name of the variable, so in your case would be env.IDEA_HOME as the Name.

Comment: The general issue which I also have is how can one export an idea setting that is project or ide specific (set in the idea UI for it's optins) int an ant invocation such that the value is inherited from the ide or project setting at invocaton time  ie: have macros representing the IDE settings that can be used to assign idea "Project Structure" properties to ant accessable properties ie: IDEA_HOME for , JAVA_HOME="Project SDK", "Project Root "where .idea is located" "Java Language Level", "Build Output Dir", "Project Name" etc

Comment: I need this too - a way to know the location of the invoking ".idea" project root (not the module) when an ant script is invoked an environment directory independent manner so the value adapts to the specific source tree location

Answer (score 2):

You can set variables as additional command line parameters. Here is a screenshot.

[image]

And then my  output:

```
echoproperties
#Ant properties
#Sun Mar 04 04:48:30 EST 2012
\==-buildfile
ant.core.lib=E\:\\IntelliJ IDEA 114.145\\lib\\ant\\lib\\ant.jar
ant.file=E\:\\IdeaProjects\\psiviewer\\build.xml
ant.file.psiviewer=E\:\\IdeaProjects\\psiviewer\\build.xml
ant.file.type=file
ant.file.type.psiviewer=file
ant.home=E\:\\IntelliJ IDEA 114.145\\lib\\ant
ant.java.version=1.6
ant.library.dir=E\:\\IntelliJ IDEA 114.145\\lib\\ant\\lib
ant.project.default-target=all
ant.project.name=psiviewer
ant.version=Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
awt.toolkit=sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
basedir=E\:\\IdeaProjects\\psiviewer
dir.idea=e\:/idea11
file.encoding=windows-1252
file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
```

You see `dir.idea` is set to what we passed to ant.

Comment: Is there any way to get the location programmatically in idea, using a macro etc?  That is for the current instance of idea that is invoking the script so one doesn't have to change the setting whenever a different user is running the build or it is on another machine or you have an old version if idea installed?

Comment: This sets properties relative to the module - not inherited from the root project configuration that invokes the module build.  This is the desire - a module may be present in several projects and knowing which project invoked the build is the need - in my case knowing the root ".idea" of the project that is building the module.

Answer (score 1):

Problem: Run ant build within IntelliJ, let ant build property to use IntelliJ Path Variables value

Solution:

1. Added path variable **QC1_SHELL_DEPLOY** to intelliJ
   [IntelliJ Settings ->Path Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehGbs.png)
2. In your **Ant Build** window (views -> Tool Windows -> Ant Build),
   right click on your ant script (assuming you have one added), click **properties**.
   create a property for ant script **qc_deploy_dir**.
   [property for ant script with arbitrary value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2koJ.png)
3. Open **ant.xml** in your project .idea/ant.xml, change the line defining **qc_deploy_dir** to use IntelliJ Path Variable **$QC1_SHELL_DEPLOY**
   [image: property change for ant.xml]
4. Go back to your **properties** window for ant script, now **qc_deploy_dir** is picking up **QC1_SHELL_DEPLOY** value.